# Is there a way to download compilation artifacts from a travis-ci build?

Tags: rust, travis-ci

I'm working on an open source project and I made a pull request. This project has travis-ci set up to check all incoming pull requests, so it did and it failed. [The error it failed with](https://travis-ci.org/TeXitoi/structopt/builds/575667984?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification) is fairly cryptic and tells me about a bug in the `rustc` compiler, no wonder it filled me with curiosity and wish to investigate.

This CI account belongs to the project's author (not me) so I tried to [reproduce the build on my own account](https://travis-ci.org/CreepySkeleton/structopt/builds/575687606). The very same commit *passed*. Not to mention the same passing situation on my local laptop.

The only thing I can think about is some kind of caching of build artifacts travis does.

So here we are: I have a link to the failing build and I'd like to download the build artifacts produced so I could dig into It or at least report this bug to the `rustc` team.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: This is probably not the right place for this. There is [cargo-bisect-rustc](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/cargo-bisect-rustc) which especially does what you ask for. If you [open an Issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/new) people will help you with it. (edit:) After looking at the CI log, it looks like it is [Issue #63161](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63161), but not 100% sure.

Comment: @hellow thanks, it's good to know. The bug seems pretty much the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download rust artifacts from the [ci server](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/rust-lang-ci2) (`https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/rust-lang-ci2`), but only for 167 days<sup>[2](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/cargo-bisect-rustc/blob/be941d7d3e15f0ee795c3394fde663b23d5820fc/src/main.rs#L55)</sup>.

An example for a build artifact would be

> `https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/rust-lang-ci2/rustc-builds-alt/003382e4150984cb476047b3925edf8d75df2d59/rust-nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz`

There is the [cargo-bisect-rustc](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/cargo-bisect-rustc/) tool which can help you with bisecting a problem.

---

As a note: your problem is most likely an incremental compiler bug already covered in https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63161